# How to know from which site a customer is redirected to our store

Tags: magento-1.8, customer, ecommerce-tracking

My client wants to advertise about their magento store on different sites, and they wanted to know from which site a customer is redirected that they can give some benefits to that site owner.

As my way, I suggest them that add a unique reference code in each advertisement URL which redirect to magento store. they are accepted it.

Now my question is **how I need to find out which from site a customer is redirected to magento store.?**

Comment: What is problem in the question? why it is downvoted can you clear it

Answer (score 4):

1. May be you can use Google analytics here?
2. Also, you can store the unique code in the session from the first visit, and then save it to the database if the customer decided to register
3. Many our clients generate coupons for 3-5% discount and give them to affiliate sites, then people apply coupons at the checkout and you can see the best performing affiliate by coupon usage report.